# How can I retrieve data from a page?

Tags: django, feincms

I am using FeinCMS. I want to do some processing on a page object before it goes to the template for rendering.

In my view I have the code :

```
this_page = Page.objects.best_match_for_path(request.path)
```

which correctly gets the page for the path I am on.

I really want to get some data out of this page.

Is there a function I can call to get the data ? such as :

```
this_page = Page.objects.best_match_for_path(request.path)
data = this_page.get_content_for_region('main')
```

I can't find anything in the readthedocs pages to answer this.
I am not interested in templates or rendering the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `this_page.content` - it's a `ContentProxy` that makes all content types of your regions available. In other words, if you have a template definition like so:

```
Page.register_templates({
    'title': 'Standard template',
    'path': 'base.html',
    'regions': (
        ('main', 'Main content area'),
        ('sidebar', 'Sidebar'),
    ),
})
```

You can loop over `this_page.content.main`and `this_page.content.sidebar`:

```
for content in this_page.content.main:
    print(content.render())
```